# Java: fetching generic class parameters at runtime

Tags: java, generics, parameterized

I have two classes, one abstract, one concrete:

```
abstract class Generator<T>;
class ConGenerator<T extends Complex<Z,Y>, Z extends Something1, Y extends Something2> extends Generator<T>;
```

Due to change in the number of parameters (I think), I cannot get the parameter classes at runtime using the usual approach with `ParametrizedType`, i.e.

```
ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
Type[] type = genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments();
```

All I am getting is the name I used for the param, `T`. I would appreciate any help in tackling this problem, I have already searched the web and used some libraries other people wrote for such problems; no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem**

It is not always possible to infer type parameters given the runtime class, and yours is such a case. The root problem is that all instances of a generic class (irrespective of their type parameters) share the same runtime class, i.e.:

```
new ArrayList<Integer>().getClass() == new ArrayList<String>().getClass()
```

Therefore, it is impossible to discover the type parameters given just the runtime class, if that class is generic and different instances of that class can use different values for the type parameter. (Yes, we can find the type parameter for class `X<T extends String>`, because String is final, are therefore the only possible argument. Likewise, we can find the type parameters of List if we know the runtime class is `class MappedList<T> implements List<String> { ... }`).

In contrast, it is always possible to infer the type parameters of a super class if the runtime class is not generic - that's what all those libraries and code examples floating around the net do with various degrees of sophistication. For instance, if you have:

```
class StringArrayList extends ArrayList<String> { ... }
```

you can discover that the type argument to ArrayList is `String`. This also works with anonymous classes (as long as they are not generic), because:

```
new ArrayList<String>() {}.getClass() != new ArrayList<Integer>() {}.getClass()
```

but fails with generic classes such as

```
ArrayList<T> makeList(T t) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(t) {};
}
```

because

```
makeList("2").getClass() == makeList(2).getClass()
```

**The Solution**

If you need the type at runtime, you will need to provide it by other means, typically by passing the `Class` object to the constructor. You can also use a super type token (an instance of a non-generic, usually anonymous, subclass of the desired type, which allows you to discover type parameters by reflection). This has the advantage that type parameters that are themselves generic can be expressed, too.

If you only need the class for a particular thing, there may be simpler alternatives. For instance, if you simply need to create new instances of the type parameter, a factory (method) pattern is quite a bit simpler :-)

Comment: "runtime class is not generic" is not necessary. It is only necessary that it is not generic (has a specific parameter with which it uses to extend its superclass) in the parameter that you care about. Other generic parameters don't matter. For example, `class StringArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<String>` would work equally well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I will look at the factory patterns :)